# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I am using `spring boot 1.5.1`, `springSecurityVersion 3.2.3` and `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` versions but I am getting below exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationObject(AuthUtils.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect.getAdditionalExpressionObjects(SpringSecurityDialect.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.context.AbstractDialectAwareProcessingContext.computeExpressionObjects(AbstractDialectAwareProcessingContext.java:113) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.context.AbstractProcessingContext.getExpressionObjects(AbstractProcessingContext.java:132) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.computeExpressionObjects(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:197) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:115) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE
```

What is the mistake in my configuration?

Comment: @g00glen00b Hi: so what change require in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, you are using Spring Security 3.2.3, but also the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency, which only works for Spring Security 4.x.

Due to this incompatibility, the Thymeleaf dependency can't find certain classes, which is why it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

The solution is to use a compatible library by either:

1. Upgrading the Spring Security version to **v4.x**. Normally, Spring boot 1.3 and higher come with Spring Security 4.x by default. So theoretically, you should be able to use Spring Security 4 unless you have a conflicting dependency somewhere. Check your dependency tree for the root cause why you are using Spring Security 3.2.3 if you didn't manually do this.
2. Downgrading the Thymeleaf dependency to `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3`, for example when using Maven:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
       <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```